Capture Microphone in the Background?
I'm working on an audio recorder project - capturing voice notes, that kind of thing. So far, it works and the audio is recorded, then appended to an audio tag on the page for immediate playback
However, this functionality only seems to work on mobile when the phone is unlocked (Android/Chrome). Sometimes I like to take audio notes when out on a walk, or in other circumstances where I can't have my phone unlocked and out. Given that the user has already consented to microphone permissions and initiated a recording, is there any way that I can continue this recording when the phone is locked? It seems a weird limitation if not...
Here's what I'm using to capture the recording:
const chunks = [];
let recorder = null;

async function beginCapture(){
  let audioStream;
  try {
    audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });
  } catch {
    alert("Permission denied!");
    return;
  }

  recorder = new MediaRecorder(audioStream);
  recorder.ondataavailable = (e) => chunks.push(e.data);
  recorder.onstop = () => saveRecordedAudio(new Blob(chunks)); 
  recorder.start();
}

function saveRecordedAudio(blob){
  //todo: actually save - we'll just output for now
  const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const audio = new Audio(url);
  audio.controls = true;
  document.body.appendChild(audio);
  audio.onload = () => URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

//called on button press
function stopRecording(){
  recorder.stop();
}


Its unlikely going to be allowed on several levels. The browser isn't the active app, and the phone is locked.

@scunliffe I can kind of understand that, but at the same time there are plenty of other apps that are able to access the microphone in the background. There's a few websites that offer audio calls or other features that don't necessarily need foreground access, but if the browser doesn't allow it then I suppose it doesn't allow it!

@Luke I created an issue for that on Chromium's bug tracker a while ago. https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41490107
